# How to use several delimiters for a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am new to using the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class in Java, and cant seem to find an example of how to use the or function when creating a pattern.

I need to use a delimiter of a pattern, so my three delimiters would be: `/`, `-`, and a new line `\n`. How would I implement this for creating a pattern as such:

```
Pattern p = Pattern("/"|"/"|\n);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern with `character class`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-/\\n]");
```

[**Read more about RegEx**](http://regular-expressions.info)